# How to change color of error output in terminal of Ubuntu 20.4 LTS run in WLS

Tags: command-line, colors

I run Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS inside WLS of Windows 10 Pro version 20H2.
Terminal has error output in such dark red, which is on black background practically unreadable.

For example I run `sudo pip3 install pycairo` and it ends with an error.

[image: Screen Example]

I tried:

- change Properties of terminal right in windows and change pop_text from dark-red to even something like yellow made no change
- set terminal via gtk-3.0 CSS .. no change seen

> ```
>  $ cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
>       terminal-window vte-terminal {
>           background-color: #470732;
>       }
> ```

- various hints here on stack but they usually refer to gnome terminal on normally installed Ubuntu, not for LWS version of terminal window

Just to clarify:

- this is not standalone and normal instance of Ubuntu OS, it is Ubuntu installed into LWS Windows 10 Pro and installed from Microsoft Store
- therefore it's not terminal window in usual X but window in/from Windows 10
- I do not need to colorize output of my script or some custom outputs from my scripts
- I would like to change **global color scheme** for all Ubuntu terminal windows no matter who opened them, and not just for current Windows session but for any terminal opened in future

Any idea where to change color scheme (especially for error outputs) permanently for all users ?

[EDIT-UPDATE]
Partial solution is to revert default colors in window Properties to white-ish background with dark/black text. Then that dark red error output is readable.
[LWS window Properties workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igx02.png)